# How do I extend the typings of Express.Application to give typings for app.locals

Tags: typescript, express

In our application, we're adding quite a few config objects to app.locals that get used in our middleware.

```
const app = Express();
app.locals = {
  someConfig: config
}
```

We currently have custom typings for the Request object that work without fail

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    featureFlags?: FeatureFlag;
  }
}
```

I know `locals` comes from Express.Application so I tried this, and it doesn't work.

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Application {
    locals: {
      someConfig: config;
    };
  }

  export interface Request {
    featureFlags?: FeatureFlag;
  }
}
```

Has anyone successfully added types to app.locals?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend locals from within the Application type definition like you were trying to do. However, locals is based on the expressjs Locals type, which you can extend:

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Locals {
      someConfig: config;
    }
  }
}
```

Tip:  It is helpful when investigating things like this if you are using a smart IDE (such as VScode or others) where you can right click on something like `this.app.locals` and select "Go to type definition", which is how I found the above.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but still...
From the express declaration file:

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    // These open interfaces may be extended in an application-specific manner via declaration merging.
    // See for example method-override.d.ts (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/method-override/index.d.ts)
    interface Request {}
    interface Response {}
    interface Application {}
  }
}
```

Just declare global namespace `Express` and extend interfaces that you need.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using a new declaration file, you can go to the original file declaration in **node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts**.
And Search for the **Application interface**.
The trick is to **define another property on that interface**, and all your routes will have access to that, similar to the locals property.

```js
  export interface Application<
    Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any> 
> extends EventEmitter, IRouter, Express.Application {
    //Make sure to keep all the others properties on the interface
    locals: Locals 
    db: mongoDb.Db //Here is the db key I've added, and all my routes can access it, just like the locals property.

 ];
}
```

Now you can assign a value to that property with `app.db ="whatever you need"` with all the autocompletion.
And within your routes handler or middleware you can have access to it with `req.app.db`.

Comment: you shouldn't modify things directly in node_modules because they will get overwritten when you npm install, won't go to your repo, and many, many other reasons